Email tracking for Sonoma without approval request
I am looking for an email service which provides an email tracking feature and works on Sonoma. I used to use the excellent Mailbutler before upgrading to Sonoma, however since the upgrade to Sonoma, Mailbutler is no longer an option for me because when linking my email address it asks for an approval from my IT department -- which was not required before upgrading to Sonoma.
Any recommendation for a service that provides email tracking and works for Sonoma, but does not require IT approval?

Is this a company machine? Why not just get approval from the IT department?

I tried asking the IT department but they are extremely slow in replying and I really need something working ASAP

Mail plugins require admin rights to install with Sonoma, so alternatives won't help. If email tracking is crucial for your jobs, there probably is a way to expedite your request.

Let’s keep this to one question. VM options are well covered on the site already.
